# My follower is attacking someone. Can I get him/her to stop?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was fighting a dragon and civilians were getting in the way, I guess I accidentally hit one of the civilians. Now he has gone aggro on me and Lydia is trying to defend me. I just want to avoid him and not kill him. How can I get Lydia to stop attacking him?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a calm spell to get them to stop fighting and fast travel away. They should chill out after a few in-game days have passed without them seeing each other. Alternatively, if you have an entrance to a different cell nearby (indoors -> outdoors, one dungeon level -> different dungeon level, etc), you could try going through and fast traveling before the NPC can give chase. The safest bet is to reload to an earlier save, though.

Answer (score 4):

If its a human take all their stuff and then wabbajack until they turn into an animal or transform into another thing. It'll last for a few seconds and then they'll act like nothing happened, give back their stuff and yeah.

I know becuase Marcurio always uses his chainlightning and he hits my dog which they start fighting. Wabbajack the best.

Answer (score 1):

There's a mod that makes people run inside their homes when a dragon attacks. So you don't have worry about them getting in your way any more. The website is http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/23906/?  To install it you just copy it to the data folder

Answer (score 0):

Walk out your house or the area, fast travel, wait a few hours (calm spell doesn't always work, even on expert level or master like I), even if the two are in that same area 'supposedly fighting'. Try to run out of there as fast as you can and Fus Roh Dah them apart (speaking of people who are too strong for illusion spells) to buy them so they wouldn't hurt each other too much too fast. Like, healing hands them quick, paralyze them (also your fighting follower whose after the NPC's), and escape the area (otherwise, they'll kill each other off). Now, outside is tricky, since you cant just hide from 'your follower as they're fighting the enemy'. Because the follower that fights for you wont care and the enemy is too busy fighting so they cant' not 'unsee you' and become pacified again.... but if its any random NPC and your illusion works, calm them and run as fast as you can away with your follower before the 'enemy' gets back up if the calm spell is in fact temporary. Wabbajack does work similarily. Don't mind the guards if they're on you. Killing them or shouting them off for a bit is the necessity to make sure your essential follower and NPC's don't die. Id rather have a bounty than lose good NPC's and followers because of friendly fire.

Answer (score -1):

Dude, the best way is a FUS RO DAH. I don't know why but it always works on Lydia. Trust me they forget everything right when they stand back up.