# Skyrim: My Best Friend is a mass Murderer!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My follower is attacking someone. Can I get him/her to stop?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54859/my-follower-is-attacking-someone-can-i-get-him-her-to-stop)

Ok, so I'm in Windhelm trying to level the pickpocket skill without cheating or using tips from wikis and I find it a good idea to try the local blacksmith. I pickpocket successfully twice and then I try for a magic ring he happens to have. I fail and he and his daughter start attacking me. I yield and they stop attacking me but my follower continues to attack them and now I can't shop in Windhelm. As we all know it is very bad to attack and kill shopkeepers so, any way to get my Follower to stop manually? I can't have him do this often, it would end badly.

Comment: What's the platform you are playing Skyrim?

Comment: Calm spell. MASS MURDERER!